# How can I convert .ive to .dae without losing texture?

Tags: 3d, openscenegraph

I was given some models in the OpenSceneGraph .ive format that I'm now attempting to convert to .dae for use in OpenSimulator. I've been trying to use osgconv to accomplish this, but no matter which output file format I try (.dae, .3ds, .obj), I receive an error message stating that the .rgb textures failed to write and the .rgb plugin could not be found, even though I have verified it is there.

When I check the model in Blender, the textures seem to be random black and white pixels.

I looked at the [osgconv user guide](http://trac.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg//wiki/Support/UserGuides/osgconv), which states:

> Some combinations of formats and texture data are not compatible, for
>   example the .RGB format is not capable of storing compressed texture
>   data. This means that if you started with a scene using .RGB external
>   texture images, converted to .IVE and have compressed your texture
>   data since converting to IVE, converting back to .OSG with external
>   .RGB texture files will not be successful.

This leads me to believe that the files I have use compressed textures. What steps do I have to take to be able to successfully convert to .dae without losing this texture data?

Comment: How did you verify the plugin exists?  If you call "osgconv --formats" from command line, you should see the osgdb_rgb plugin listed.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion from ive might also require the -O OutputTextureFiles option for it to write the textures.